# Disable product returns feature in opencart

Tags: opencart

My client doesn't accept returns. Is there any way to disable this returns feature without modifying the  template files?

Comment: You can disable returns only by hiding the relevant templates and links to them - I can advise you how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the answer is no. You have to either edit the template and/or use VQmod to alter the code where returns are refered to.

But there is no option in admin where you can disable product returns

Answer (score 1):

VERY Easy solution....just go to your cpanel and then:  /catalog/language/english/common/footer.php

There you will find a list including: "Returns"....just delete that line and click save and it will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

just add:

```
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
```

In the beginning of every class method of catalog/controller/account/return

You also have to disable the links shown in the account and footer

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of OC (3.x), this can be done by editing the footer template under the "edit themes" section in the admin control panel:

1. Go to the admin control panel.
2. Under "Design", select the theme editor.
3. From the list, select Common->footer.twig.
4. Inside "footer.twig" search for this line: `<li><a href="{{ return }}">{{text_return }}</a></li>` and remove it.
5. Save your changes.